# Car Only Starts With A Jump

Tags: electrical, battery, starting

Car will only start with a jump. Took car to Autozone had the battery,alternator and starter checked all came out good but still will not start without a jump. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Battery might be good but the Cranking Amps might be bad

Comment: You need to describe what you do, see and hear.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a loose terminal connection. Battery terminals can be loose or corroded causing low power. Enough to run but not to crank. Check for looseness & corrosion But even if not looking corroded I would clean them. Terminals can be bought for around $6 in auto parts stores & for less in a department store.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. As it stands this is a very low quality answer, as we like to see more detail - could you expand it a bit, perhaps suggesting which terminals might be loose, how they can be checked, etc.

Comment: I've edited your comment into your answer